# Extjs Comobobox duplicate display field not allowed to be set?

Tags: extjs, combobox, form-submit

I'm a newbie using Extjs 4.07. I have created a combobox (remote) queryMode. The combobox displays a list of courses. However, the institution I work for recently recoded their entire courses. So, I end up having two records with the same display field. My JSON looks like this:

```
{"result":[{"id":"90223","code":"CM12","description":"Introduction to C Programming","creditHours":"3.00","numberOfLabs":"0","contactHours":null,"chargeableCredits":null},
{"id":"2094","code":"CMPS1302","description":"Introduction to C Programming","creditHours":"3.00","numberOfLabs":"0","contactHours":null,"chargeableCredits":null}],"total":2}
```

the display field is description and the value field is id. When I select one of the items in the combobox and submit everything works fine. The problem occurs if later I selected the incorrect course and select the other one.

I have tried setting the idProperty: 'id' but to no avail. When I submit the form the value that will be sent is the one that was selected first after. Note: This only happens for duplicate course descriptions, everything else works fine.

here is some code to help explain the problem:

```
Ext.define('SIS.model.ManageCourse', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'code', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'creditHours', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'contactHours', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'chargeableCredits', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'numberOfLabs', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'selected', type: 'bool'} //for update course pre-requisites
    ]
});


Ext.define('SIS.store.ClassCourse', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'SIS.model.ManageCourse',
    pageSize: 7,
    remoteFilter: true,
    idProperty: 'id',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'course/select'
        },
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'result',
            totalProperty  : 'total',
            successProperty : 'success'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('SIS.view.class.ClassCourseCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.ClassCourseCombo',
    name: 'courseId',
    fieldLabel: 'Course',
    store: 'ClassCourse',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    pageSize: 7,
    displayField: 'description',
    valueField: 'id',
    allowBlank: false,
    hideTrigger: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    minChars: 1,
    lazyInit: false,
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function () {
            return '<div class="combo-header">{description}</div>\
                <div class="combo-item">{code}</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem with the example "The problem occurs if later I selected the incorrect course and select the other one." is confusing.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to select Intro to C Programming (CM12) but I selected Intro to C Programming (CMPS1302) by mistake. Even though I make the correction my first selection will be submitted. However, If I select another course, eg. Software Engineer, and then select Intro to C Programming (CMPS1302) it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug identified since version 3 I found the solution in [sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?101123-OPEN-1033-ComboBox-reports-incorrect-value-when-non-unique-display-fields-are-used) provided by Condor.

I changed the line

```
if(val.length > 0 && val != this.emptyText)
```

with

```
if(val.length > 0 && val != this.emptyText && typeof this.emptyText != 'undefined')
```

when there is no emptyText defined the result is just as if forceSelection was set to false even when explicitly set to true. small fix.

Answer (score 0):

Having same display value for different rows in combo box is confusing at least for the end user. Why don't you create a calculated field like this:

```
fields: [
  { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
  { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'display', type: 'string', convert: function(v, r) {
     return r.get('id') + ' ' + r.get('description');
  }}
}]
```

And use this `display` as your displayField.

Comment: I thought about that but if that is done then when editing the combo no results will be returned since the display field is used as the query to fetch results from server. I decided to use getInnerTpl instead to format the display.